# Динамически шаблон документа Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

Здравствуйте. У меня есть такой вопрос: можно ли на C# создать динамически шаблон документа Word? Тест зависимо от данных, в документе добавлялись прямоугольники, и в них эти данные.

Answer (score 1):

В Обозревателе решений щёлкаем правой кнопкой по References -> Добавить ссылку... -> Сборки -> Расширения -> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Теперь доступно

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

А на кнопке или перед завершение программы, когда нужно сделать Word-файл пишем нижеследующее

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph wordParag;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table wordTable;

//создаём новый документ Word и задаём параметры листа
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //создаём документ Word

// первый параграф
wordParag = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(Type.Missing);
wordParag.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
wordParag.Range.Font.Size = 16;
wordParag.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
wordParag.Range.Text = "Заголовок";
wordParag.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;

// второй параграф, таблица из 10 строк и 2 колонок
wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(Type.Missing);
wordParag.Range.Tables.Add(wordParag.Range, 10, 2, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wordTable = wordDoc.Tables[1];
wordTable.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
wordTable.Range.Font.Size = 12;

//задаём ширину колонок и высоту строк
wordTable.Columns.PreferredWidthType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPoints;
wordTable.Columns[1].SetWidth(200f, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
wordTable.Rows.SetHeight(20f, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly);                        
wordTable.Rows.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;
wordTable.Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
wordTable.Range.Select();

//заполняем ячейки таблицы
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
        wordTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = "Ячейка " + i.ToString() + " " + j.ToString();

//сохраняем документ, закрываем документ, выходим из Word
wordDoc.SaveAs("D:\\word.docx");
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```